# How to read and edit a json file and send it as a request in karate dsl

Tags: cucumber, dsl, karate

The code i am trying out is :

Given url ApiAdminURL

And path AdminPath

And header apigateway-apikey = apiGatewayKey

And header apigateway-basepath = 'lambdaTest'

** json myReq = read('users.json')

** set myReq.apiConf.subscriptionTiers = ["Unlimited"]

** print 'my subscriptions : ', myReq.apiConf

And request read('myReq.json')

When method post

Then status 200

i can read the json file and get it in a variable "myReq" and now i want to send this edited myReq. json as my request but i am not able to do that.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `And request read('myReq.json')`

Shouldn't this work !

```
And request myReq
```